# Sensor Detect Open/Close

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find or create something in VB.Net that will detect an open/closed switch. I am currently looking for the proper I/O board that will communicate with Windows 7 via USB or RS-232. I have been searching but everything leads me to Raspberry Pi or the like. I want to create a simple GUI in vb.net that will give me Red/Green when I magnet switch is open/closed. If anyone reading this has examples of what I am looking for and/or can point me in the right direction, I would really really appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Try searching for "USB button".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

National instruments NI6501 or 6008. NI SDK called NIDAQ is free and comes bundled with vb.net and c# examples.

Comment: Although it's a useful suggestion, it is best not to give answers to off-topic questions (in this case the question is off-topic because it is asking for product recommendations).